# Positive and comparative degree of same adjective

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-meaning, sentence-structure, adjectives, comparative-degree

> A little less virtue and I might have lived longer.

Reference: THE ANGEL AND THE AUTHOR -AND OTHERS by Jerome K. Jerome

As *less* is a comparative degree of little, it's here being used right after its positive degree of adjective. Are there any other examples where positive and comparative degrees of same adjectives have been used in quick succession like the above mentioned example? Furthermore, what does the writer want to say here?

Comment: You're mistakenly assuming some inherent semantic connection between ***little*** and ***less*** in the cited context. ***A little less, a little more, a lot less, a lot more*** are all perfectly natural collocations - it's completely irrelevant that in some *other* contexts, ***a little*** and ***less*** are associated with ***small[er]***, whereas ***a lot*** and ***more*** are associated with ***big[ger]***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The author is speaking from the point of view of a soul ascending to heaven, that is someone who has recently died.

And the soul observes that "if I had been slightly less virtuous, I might have lived to an older age"  (it's not clear why the soul believes this)

"A little" is functioning as an adverb, modifying "less", and meaning "slightly".

You can make all sorts of similar sentences. I'm not sure how *idiomatic* they are:

(a person has rushed while preparing dinner and spoiled the food)

> A little less haste and the dinner might not have been ruined.

or with "more"

> A little more care and your essay might have been worth an 'A'

Comment: And less is functioning as a quantifier, not an adjective.